# How to add the data received from UIAlertview text field to a local variable?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have button set up, and when it gets clicked, an alertview will appear with a text field. I want to get the data from that variable and trigger an addition function which adds the value of the text field to a local variable and displays the data in a label. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/delegate) property of `UIAlertView` and have that object conform to [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html). Namely, respond to [`alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView%3aclickedButtonAtIndex%3a), during which you can inquire regarding [`textFieldAtIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex%3a).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already got the UIAlertView with a UITextField (either using the UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput, UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, or UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput).

I'm also going to assume that you've set up the UIAlertViewDelegate so that it gets called properly when a button on the UIAlertView is pressed. So, to get the value of the UITextField, in your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` you add the following code (assuming only one UITextField - if you have multiple, just change the parameter passed to textFieldAtIndex:

```
NSInteger textFieldValueAsInteger = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text integerValue];
NSInteger finalValue = textFieldValueAsInteger + someOtherIntegerThatYouAlreadyDeclared;
```

Displaying it largely depends on your your UILabel etc are set up, but basically:

```
UILabel *labelToDisplayResults = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:labelToDisplayResults];

[labelToDisplayResults setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", finalValue]];
```

That should do it. Let me know if you have any other follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a delegate for the alert view, and that object should adopt the [UIAlertViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html). The delegate will then receive a `-alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` message before the alert is dismissed. Your delegate's implementation of that method can get the text from whatever text fields are in the alert -- use `-textFieldAtIndex:` to get the different text fields.